# What features is required for DLUX to show the normal login page in Opendaylight Sodium

Tags: opendaylight, sodium

The environment: branch "stable/sodium"
The Command "feature:install odl-dlux-core" is installed and activated without error. However, the webpage "http://:8181/index.html" shows a empty webpage in gray. What other features/bundles are required for DLUX?

Answer (score 0):

DLUX has not been active or part of any OpenDaylight release for ~2 years, so
it should not be available in sodium either. Are you sure your feature:install
odl-dlux-core worked? what does karaf.log show? I'm guessing there should be
some errors.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I knew that DLUX was not an official project of ODL anymore, but it's still available in ODL's Github repo. And DLUX owns the stable branch "stable/sodium" (https://github.com/opendaylight/dlux/tree/stable/sodium). So I'm confused. btw, according to the karat log, I'm sure that odl-dlux-core works well. And from the debug console of Chrome browser, everything could be loaded. But the frontend "index.html#topology" shows nothing but a grey wall. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know much more to help you with this. If it's just a gray page with no logos or menus, then sounds like a legit problem. If you are just not seeing any network devices, maybe it's because you have nothing connected to the controller?